# GET url from java music player

Tags: java, wireshark

Basicly I use wireshark to retrieve URL's that i need,
in some cases I can' t have the real URL from java music player.

Is there a method or with wireshark is not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done?

Comment: Simply use wireshark.Open the program, start capturing and i can find the URL's of media streamed.But with some java players I am not able to find out the URL of media played.

Comment: I think, example of capture with good and bad case and detailed description on them would give a better start for this question.